# Why is the Tetragrammaton vowelized in Siddurim and in Sefarim?

Tags: jewish-books, shemos-sacred-names, writing-printing, vowels-nekudot

I've often found that the Tetragrammaton (Shem Havayah) is often vowelized in siddurim and sefarim. Since we *b'davkah* don't say the Shem Havayah how it is spelled, why are the vowels included?

Also, are the vowels usually included an accurate reflection of how it was pronounced?

I've noticed that in Artscroll siddurim, they do spell out the yud, then heh, then vav, then heh, albeit without the nikkudos. This seems to make sense to me, as then someone reading it would have to go out of their way to pronounce it.

I do understand the difference in vowelization on whether it's *Hashem/Elokim* verses just *Hashem/Ado-noi*, but why do we print them in places other than a chumash or a tanach?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9751/759

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason why, but (B"H) this coming *Yom Kippur* we'll need to know how to say it.

Comment: I have no doubt that this is a question which editors and publishes will answer subjectively as even the decision to print the yod-kay-vav-kay is also variable (some siddurm just use the double yod). It might be as a reminder that one is specifically NOT supposed to pronounce it in any way other than the transposed nekudot of "adonai" (though with the proper shva replacing the initial kamatz as the yod replaces the aleph) but I don't think it is a function of anything other than editorial choice.

Comment: @Dan still, think of it like this: according to those who see use in vowelizing it, what purpose does it serve?

Comment: As guessed, as a reminder of what we should NOT be saying. Instead of focusing on the letters and imagining or trying to intuit the shem, we are reminded to say the replacement and move on. Purely psychological, not halachik, but it satisfies a need for some.

Comment: May be driven by psychology, but it is misguided.  It is far too easy for a beginner to mix up with יהיה and והיה when there are vowel marks on all three.  I had to make especial effort not to type the name just in writing this comment.  My siddur has no nekudot on the name, and I am glad.  BTW I believe that the verse in Zekhariah 14:9 was originally an alliteration back when the name was still spoken, but I have no evidence for this.

Answer (score 10):

There some times where (according to *kabala* or something) one should have a certain vowelization of the name in mind (while still saying "*Adonay*" of course). You'll sometimes see the name with four *tzere*s or with four *sh'va*s or the like then. I know nothing more about this than I've just written.

Otherwise, the vowelization seems to be to point to its pronunciation as "*Adonay*" or as "*Elohim*": it has the appropriate vowels for whichever pronunciation should be used. (Note that a *chataf patach* and a *chataf segol* are variations on the *sh'va*, so appear as a *sh'va* under a *yod*.)

Comment: Those other vocalizations are associated with _tzirufim_, or permutations of the letters and vowels based on their appearance in other words - often surrounding the Tetragrammaton in a _pasuk_ or some other context - which contribute to the _kavanos_ one has when reciting them.

Answer (score 1):

One can also look into the connection of vowels with sefirot (chased, gevurah, tifferet, etc), different aspect/attributes of Hashem