# Shiluvim and Ashkenazim

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names, ashkenazi, kavana-intent, nusach-edot-hammizrach

In many Edot haMizrach siddurim, the tetragrammaton is printed with kavvanot (called shiluvim) in the final ה. Is it appropriate, according to Ashkenazi poskim, to pay attention to these kavanot?

Comment: What are the kavanot that someone should have when looking at the "shiluvim"?

Comment: If i ever happen to be using an Edot Hamizrach siddur, i just ignore them, because i have no idea what they're supposed to mean.

Comment: @Scimonster, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15396/why-is-the-tetragrammaton-vowelized-in-siddurim-and-in-sefarim, for some examples

Comment: @Shokhet, I am unsure, however the halachot regarding Kabbalah are significantly more lenient among Sephardim. I would ask, but I am unsure about whether it is mutar for me to learn the answer. (I actually had that issue over Shabbat, where I asked a Chabad shliach about one of their minhagim and some of the sources were not permissible for me to study).

Comment: Huh. Interesting. It's a little odd that you're not allowed to learn certain things, but I suppose you (and, *kal v'chomer*, me) don't have sufficient background in Kabbalah to learn these things.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Could you edit your question to explain what kavvanot are? Would be a lot stronger. Thanks    -is definitely not allowed to learn kabbalah>