# What are the reasons or rules for the different variations in vowels on the Tetragrammaton?

Tags: tanach, shemos-sacred-names, vowels-nekudot

I'm aware that the vowels of the Tetragrammaton are unknown and i'm not asking what they are.

I see a lot of variation in the vowels placed or not placed, on the Tetragrammaton.

Sometimes a hataph patach on the first letter, sometimes a shva, sometimes a hataph segol.

Sometimes a holam on the second letter, sometimes no vowel.

Sometimes a kamatz on the third letter, sometimes a hiriq on the third letter.

I'm interested to know what reasons there are for when it's written with some vowels and not other vowels..  I see a pattern where it is spelt with a yud under the vav, every time it follows aleph,dalet,nun,yud. So it seems maybe there are some rules or conventions.

Examples below

[image]

The Mechon Mamre site for that verse has the word with just the two vowels, and the yud with the shva. http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26e4.htm

[image]

I see in bibleworks the cholam

[image]

I see it seems maybe every case of aleph,daled,nun,yud followed by yud,heh,vav,heh  there is a chirik under the third letter of yud,heh,vav,heh

e.g.

[image]

and in that Kings example a vav with a cholam

[image]

Comment: related- http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76917/why-the-masoretes-wrote-the-tetragrammaton-this-way and  http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/9173/what-does-qr-perpetuum-mean

Comment: also argon's answer here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78070/explanation-of-kri-u-khtiv-vowel-for-first-letter-of-tetragrammaton confirms http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/b-hebrew/2005-September/025824.html

Comment: i just added to my answer

Comment: It depends on whether you should say _Adoshem_ or _Elokim,_ and whether the editor omitted the _cholam_ or not. A better question is, whether one had to put the _chataf segol_ on the ש- prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are kabolistic ideas in different nekudot of the Name see [this](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/search.aspx?searchText=%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93&searchWhere=all).
(See second line from the bottom (and footnote 25) [here](http://otzar770.com/library/main_book.asp?nBookId=76&cPartLetter=b&nPageNumber=331))

---

But the way I was tought all the examples you bring are just ways to hint to us how to read it

Most of them are hinting (having very similar nekudot) to Adonoy
 in the the last 3 examples they are hinting (having very similar nekudot) to Elokim

Not always are they exact:

The shva is a hint to the hataph patach and to hataph segol, depending on the rest of the nekudot.
The holam is sometimes skipped

Since the nekuda on the 3rd letter is enough for the hint

---

There is mishnah Berurah that when you imagine the name before you at all times it should be with the nekudot of the word fear
Source [mishna Berurah 1.4](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.1.4?with=all&lang=he)

---

**Edit**
another reason of the 2 versions when it is pronounced Adonoy

[shulchan aruch harav 5.2](http://www.chabad.org/3268367)

> When, however, [the name] is written as י‑ה‑ו‑ה, there are those who pronounce the alef with a shva, for this is the vowel of [the corresponding initial letter which is] the yud of the name י‑ה‑ו‑ה. Others pronounce the alef with a chataf patach, using the same vowel as the alef of the name A-donai.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "The sva is a hint to the hataph patach and to hataph segol, depending on the rest of the nekudot."  So, Why is the shva used as a hint? And how does it depend?

Comment: @barlop Thank you,.  The word Elohim and the word Adonoy  have each have 3 nekudot, if you skip first one it will not be a good hint, but if you change the first nekida a little (make a hint to what it needs to be) by putting a sheva instead of a hataph parach it is still hint to the correct way of reading it

Comment: what i'm asking is why would a shva hint to a hataph patach / hataph vowel?  Is it just because hataph vowels involve a shva.. or is there some other reason e.g. like  i've heard something along the lines of that some letters like Chet cannot take a vocal shva, but can take a composite shva(hataph vowel), or a silent shva.

Comment: also how do we know that shva is just a hint and not the real vowel under the yud?  there are many names like yuh hoshua    yud with shva.

Comment: @barlop my guess is your first idea, but there might be another reason, I just am not an expert in this subject

Comment: @barlop I know from being tough I do not have a source, b"n I will look for a source later today

Comment: @barlop what I explained seems to fit with what it says in Wikipedia in the 2nd and 3rd paragraph see https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/יהוה

Comment: my hebrew translation skills are very low so I can't make good use of that link.

Comment: @barlop there they bring the same idea I brought

Comment: @barlop (in response to one of my comments).. I think a composite shva is considered a vocal shva. There is a rule that a gutteral can't take a simple vocal shva.. i.e. when a gutteral has a simple shva, the shva has to be silent.  (hence a gutteral with  at the beginning of a word, if it has a shva, would have to have a vocal composite shva..  But a yud is not a gutteral so a yud can have a shva)  So the only way in which it might be a hint is that a compound shva is a type of shva.

Comment: @barlop I have an Artscroll Chumash mikraot gedolot there they do not put any nikud under the name, unless it is one that is  read elokim

Comment: @barlop so you see that the hint does not need to be clear it is enough a hint of a hint or as Artscroll did, no hint at all

Comment: @barlop the problem with no nikud is you do not see clearly on which nikud to sing (accent (put the taam))

Comment: isn't it always on the last syllable for the name?

Comment: @barlop that is why they decided to not put anything (they will not loos)

Comment: though wouldnt a shva on an aleph break the rules of hebrew grammar?  aleph can't take any kind of shva, and other gutterals. I heard the rule is that aleph can only take compound shva, it cant take a simple shva. And other gutterals cannot take a vocal simple shva but can take a compound shva or simple silent shva.So if aleph takes a simple shva it breaks the rule. The rule that Aleph can't take a simple shva,n the rule that no gutteral can take a vocal simple shva.  (so, all gutterals can't take a vocal simple shva, and aleph  is even stricter in that it also canot take a silent simple shva)

Comment: I notice the shulchan aruch says "When, however, [His] name is [not only pronounced but] also written as א‑ד‑נ‑י (A-donai),"     I didn't know a-donai ever meant his name.. but yeah, since it literally means "my lords" it can't be that so it must be a name.  I guess it is his name.. Is A-donai as holy a name as E-l Shaddai and E-l Elyon?

Comment: @barlop I am not compitent to answer the first question but for the answer to the last one see this question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23463/5120

Answer (score 5):

The divine name YHVH is always an instance of *Qere and Ketiv*. The convention used for representing *Qere and Ketiv* is to give the consonants of the written word but point the consonants with the vowels of the word that is to be read instead of it.

The default choice for what to read for YHVH is Adonay, so most often YHVH is pointed with the vowels of Adonay. If, however, YHVH follows an actual written instance of Adonay, then the default is inappropriate, so Elohim is used instead, and the consonants of YHVH are pointed with the vowels of Elohim.

Comment: Please see the op's question in the comment to my answer, maybe you can help

Comment: @hazoriz, I posted a separate question to try to get answers for that point: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78070/explanation-of-kri-u-khtiv-vowel-for-first-letter-of-tetragrammaton

Comment: If you can make the point in your answer about the difference in regards to Sheva and the difference in regards to absence and presence of Cholam,  and if you change the phrase "vowels of", in  "vowels of Adonay"   "vowels of Elohim"  to vowels 'like'  to be clear that it's not exactly like, then I can accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

No doubt paquda is correct in saying that it's a case of ktiv and keri, but it will rarely have vowels exactly of elohim or exactly of adonai. Every case the vowels are either like elohim or like adonai. But rarely exactly like.

A) When it(YHVH) has vowels like Adonai, the difference is that there is usually a simple shva under the Yud rather than a composite shva. (at least looking at the WLC)

B) When it(YHVH) has vowels like Elohim, the difference is that in most cases there is a simple shva under the yud of YHVH.

C) Usually there is no cholam on the vav of YHVH(funnily enough mechon mamre's text never puts the cholam on there, and bible.ort.org's text has the cholam on all of them. The WLC has a mixture, where thousands of cases don't have the vav and around 50-90 do)

And interestingly, in WLC, for Judges 16:28 you get a composite shva under the yud, and a vav over the first heh, so the vowels (hataph segol, cholam, chirik), are exactly the vowels of elohim, in that instance. (I don't think there is any case in the WLC, of YHVH matching the vowels of adonai or elohim exactly, other than that one where it matches elohim exactly).

The reason for the composite shva(on the aleph of elohim and of adonai), changed to a simple shva(on the yud of YHVH), is likely because(or at least something to do with the fact that), yud is allowed a simple vocal shva. (unlike aleph, which is in adonai and elohim, an aleph's vocal shva has to be composite).

i.e. grammatically a gutteral e.g. Aleph, isn't meant to take a simple vocal shva but can take a composite shva, so adonai and elohim take a composite shva. So it's normal for a letter that would normally take a simple vocal shva, to take a composite shva if the letter is gutteral. (Note that there are cases of non-gutteral letters in tanach taking composite shva too)  Yud doesn't have that restriction that aleph has of not being able to take a simple vocal shva.

The answerer, Pekuda, does explain when YHVH has the vowels like Adonai and when it has the vowels like Elohim. (I say *like* adonai and *like* elohim, rather than 'of' adonai and elohim, because see points A,B,C).

His answer does leave open the question of why is it that sometimes the cholam is in there, (i.e. the cholam of elohim and adonai), leaving all the vowels in there, and sometimes not.  And indeed sometimes with the vowels like in the WLC,  elohim(1 Kings 2:26, Psalms 140:8, Isaiah 50:4), and sometimes with the vowels like adonai(Gen 3:14, Gen 9:26).

Note- if you have a text editor with regex search and the tanach loaded in, you can use the regex `[\u05D9][\u0500-\u05AF\u05BC-05CF]*[\u05B0-\u05BB][\u0500-\u05AF\u05BC-05CF]*[\u05D4][\u0500-\u05AF\u05BC-05CF]*[\u05B0-\u05BB][\u0500-\u05AF\u05BC-05CF]*[\u05D5][\u0500-\u05AF\u05BC-05CF]*[\u05B0-\u05BB][\u0500-\u05AF\u05BC-05CF]*[\u05D4]` to search for e.g. YHWH with cholam.

Note- It may be a bit flawed to look to the WLC for something as fine as this, (As the leningrad is thought to be a bit sloppy and doesn't even correspond with its own mesora notes in its markings), perhaps the Aleppo Codex sheds more light, though it isn't in digital text form and may just be in pdf or jpg which makes it harder to check).

Comment: barlop if you think paquda got the answer right (which I happen to agree), then you should accept it instead of accepting hazoriz garbled answer.

Comment: @Bach  paquda wasn't entirely correct. Paquda said for example "often YHVH is pointed with the vowels of Adonay"      And that's not correct.  YHVH doesn't ever have exactly the vowels of adonai  because adonai has a *hataph patach*, and on the first letter, and the Yud/first letter of YHVH  doesn't have a hataph patach under it (and so isn't even pronounced at all the same , given current pronunciations of those vowels, and any pronunciation since it is a different vowel or half vowel ).

Comment: @Bach also, Hazorzis said this in comment, "if you change the first nekida a little (make a hint to what it needs to be) by putting a sheva instead of a hataph parach it is still hint to the correct way of reading it "  ,   which switched a light bulb on in my head.  That adonai has a composite shva, and YHVH has a simple shva. So while not the same vowel, they are very similar vowels (And I was aware of the rule re gutterals not taking a vocal shva).  Pequda's answer, completely glossed over the problem and in his answer he presented it like the vowels were the same when they weren't.  .

Comment: @Bach Pequda did later comment on his answer regarding the shva , linking to a question he later asked, but there's no clarity in his answer or even in the words of his comment, of there even being a question on the first letter. There is a comment from him with link that asks re that shva, but that was posted long after Hazorzis already made his comment to me about the shva.

Comment: @barlop slight correction to myself, it looks like YHVH does sometimes have  a hataph patach under the yud.

Comment: It does have the same vowels. Chataf Patach is just a fancy Shva since it's under a gutteral. Under the Yud it doesn't need to be fancy. You can't have a regular Shva under the Alef. It's just a contextual representational difference of the same vowel.

Comment: @DoubleAA the composite shva hataph patach is pronounced differently to the simple shva (at least in our time, so not just a graphic difference).  Also looking at the WLC, the cholam is usually missing (so not the same vowels when it's missing), and i'm not sure that there's any case with the WLC where you have both the hataph patach and the cholam on YHVH, in which case it never has exactly the same vowels.  (WLC=digitized leningrad codex)

Comment: You pronounce the "p" in "sport" and "port" differently nowadays, but it's still the same letter.

Comment: @DoubleAA  I don't know if it's different in america but i'm british and I pronounce the p the same in sport and in port.  If you want that kind of example of a letter pronounced differently, you might want to use a word like `guage`

Comment: You don't aspirate only the latter? You probably don't even realize it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allophone#English

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not that familiar with the phonetic term aspirate.. I think I exhale when I say any words.  I notice the IPA seems to be the same in the UK and US for the p of sport and the p of port  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sport     
 and https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/port