# Why does the Tetragrammaton sometimes include the cholam vowel?

Tags: tanach, vowels-nekudot, shemos-sacred-names

Why does the Tetragrammaton sometimes include the cholam vowel ?

The question isn't a duplicate of [What are the reasons or rules for the different variations in vowels on the Tetragrammaton?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77277/what-are-the-reasons-or-rules-for-the-different-variations-in-vowels-on-the-tetr)

Because that question was very general. This question is far more specific.

I understand (from the answer to the previous question), that and when, YHVH is written with vowels like Adonai, and when it is written with vowels like Elohim.

What I would like to know is why is it sometimes written with the cholam, and sometimes without?

Is there any kind of rule that governs when it is written with a cholam and when not, rather like there is a rule for when it is written with vowels like adonai vs vowels like elohim?

Funnily enough, I just noticed that while my copy of the text which is the WLC(Westminster leningrad codex), which now is essentially meant to be a copy of the leningrad codex, has mostly without (like thousands without), and some with (like between 50-80 with).   Mechon Mamre don't have a cholam on any of their YHVH instances.  Whereas bible.ort seems to have the cholam on every single YHVH instance!

Comment: Probably laziness since it's all fake vowels anyway.

Comment: @DoubleAA lazyness when not included?

Comment: Are the different manuscripts consistent in where they do and don't have the cholam?

Comment: @Heshy  you mean are they consistent on which occurrences of the name have the cholam and which don't,  I very much doubt it, I think if they were then the last paragraph I wrote wouldn't be the case. There's also inconsistency in regard to when words have a meteg and when not.