# Which pronunciation-permutation of "yod, hay vav, hay" is forbidden to pronounce?

Tags: hebrew

@AvrohomYitzchok said that I should post this question as a new question. (He did not know the answer).

I was responding to a comment he made, which read

> @Sarah When Rambam says "pronounces the name [of God] with its
>   letters, yod, hay vav, hay" he means to articulate the name as it is
>   written and not with the letters Alef Daleth Nun Yod (as we pronounce
>   it). – Avrohom Yitzchok Jul 10 '16 at 20:18

And here is my question:

> Does the pronunciation of "the name [of God] with its letters, yod,
>   hay vav, hay" refer to the pronunciation as in the masoretic pointing
>   of "yod, hay vav, hay" or to any pronunciation-permutation of "yod,
>   hay vav, hay"?

I kindly request for a source for any answer. Thank you.

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9751/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you for the referral. The title of this article you referred me to is "What is the correct pronunciation of the Tetragrammaton?" This article is helpful but I am not sure it answers my question, which, in part, is 'Does the [[prohibition of]] pronunciation of "the name [of God] with its letters, yod, hay vav, hay" refer ... to any pronunciation-permutation of "yod, hay vav, hay"?'