# Pronouncing Shem Havayah in Chol Context

Tags: shemos-sacred-names

Coming back from a road trip, we passed by [this street](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Yahweh+Rd,+Olive+Branch,+MS+38654/@34.9920335,-89.8735371,19z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x887f8e4b0ce9ce6b:0x900bcaab3842310b).

How would one say the name of the street? Is it considered Shem Havayah to pronounce it that way? If not, what if it was pronounced the way the Shem is supposed to be pronounced? What if it was a different one of His Names?

That is: is one allowed to pronounce one of Hashem's Names in a context that clearly doesn't refer to Him?

Comment: That's Shem havaya? How do you know it's pronounced like that?

Comment: That was sort of part of my question. I'll edit it to make that a little clearer.

Comment: While your at it, just include the name of the street explicitly. No need to click through to find that info

Comment: Part of this seems like a dupe of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5120/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree. The end of the question seems like a duplicate, but (as it pertains to this story) the question may be based on a faulty premise - namely, that this street name is not a direct reference to the Tetragrammaton.

Comment: Yep, absolutely a dupe. Once again, I need to learn how to search better around here. :)